How to create Provider for state that is fetched asynchronously? (Flutter)
I am new to Flutter and Dart, and I am building an app where users can sign in with their Google accounts and choose a Google Sheet to read/write through the app. I have set up Google sign in, and users are able to sign in with their Google accounts and I am able to show them a list of Google Sheets in their account.
I want to store the id of the Sheet they select using SharedPreferences, and when the app starts, I want to first check if a user has signed in, and if yes, if they have already selected a Google Sheet. I am storing this data in a model called BudgetSheet -
class BudgetSheet extends ChangeNotifier {
  String? spreadsheetId;
  String? spreadsheetName;
  SharedPreferences? sharedPreferences;

  BudgetSheet({ 
    required this.spreadsheetId, 
    required this.spreadsheetName, 
    required this.sharedPreferences 
  });
}

On startup, I am getting the previously saved data asynchronously and showing the user a splash screen while the data is being loaded using a FutureBuilder -
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> initializeAuth() async {
  Map<String, dynamic> data = {};
  GoogleSignInAccount? previousUser = await googleSignIn.signInSilently();
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  String? spreadsheetId = prefs.getString('spreadsheetId');
  String? spreadsheetName = prefs.getString('spreadsheetName');
  data['user'] = previousUser;
  data['spreadsheetId'] = spreadsheetId ?? '';
  data['spreadsheetName'] = spreadsheetName ?? '';
  data['sharedPreferences'] = prefs;
  return data;
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>>? _previousAuth;

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _previousAuth = initializeAuth();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: FutureBuilder(
        future: _previousAuth,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return HomePage();
          }
          else {
            return SplashScreen();
          }
        }
      )
    );
  }

I want to wrap my MaterialApp with a ChangeNotifierProvider<BudgetSheet> instance to make the BudgetSheet model instance available globally. However, the actual data is available only after an async call, so it is not available when the MaterialApp instance is created. How can I make the BudgetSheet data available globally after it is fetched?
